# Django package import error "Invalid syntax"

Tags: python, django, pip, python-import, openpyxl

openpyxl package import throws "invalid syntax" error in virtualenv while running the django project.
While installing the package through requirements.txt file, I'm getting an error for this package in logs as follows

[image: Log in terminal]

This is the version of openpyxl I'm installing

```
openpyxl==3.0.3
```

I've tried to install the package manually again by doing a

```
pip install openpyxl
```

but this says successfully installed but failed to build openpyxl.
Any help with this issue will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: openpyxl required Python >=3.6, and you are using python 3.5 i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openpyxl required Python >=3.6, and you are using python 3.5 I think

Answer (score 1):

Update your python to version **3.6 or higher**. Go to the [python website](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and download the one for your os. Hope this helps.